# How to access a HashMap from another class

Tags: java, android, android-activity, hash, hashmap

I have currently created a hash map in one class, as shown below:

```
public static HashMap BasicDetails;
```

which I want to access from another class.
I have also put the values from the same class where the HashMap was declared as so:

```
            BasicDetails.put("currentPersonName", personName);
            BasicDetails.put("currentPersonImage", personPhoto);
            BasicDetails.put("currentPersonGooglePlusProfile", personGooglePlusProfile);
```

which takes retrieved Google account information and stores it into a hash map.

Now, in my second class, I want to access it. I did not know where to start so I declared a TextView variable known as nameValue

```
public TextView nameValue;
```

In my onCreate method, I then decided to equate this nameValue to the hash map equivalent value (currentPersonName):

```
        nameValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameValue);
        nameValue.setText(BasicDetails.get("currentPersonName"));
```

Yet the BasicDetails tag is highlighted in red, noting that it is not recognized by the class (despite the hash map being declared as public). I may also note that in the xml file I have created a blank textView object which has the id = nameValue as well.

Please help, any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT - Solution Found**

I retyped the passing of the data to be passed via Intents, will post code shortly

Comment: Prefix the BashDetails with the class name where you declared it: `MyClass.BasicDetails.get( etc )`.

Comment: it has to be your `classname.BasicDetails.get("currentPersonName")`

Comment: I find your design of app not good. Hashmap belongs to the class - if you access all content from another class then you should change your design as it looks like it belongs more to the accessing class then the one that holds ist

Comment: Make sure that the code is **working as intended** before posting on Code Review. For more information read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) and [Code Review help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either make the information available by using statics (not recommended), use some kind of database (could be as simple as a text file) or pass an Intent along with your Activity. A nice tutorial on adding information to an `Intent` is found here: http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/241-lesson-28-extras-passing-data-using-intent.html

Answer (score 0):

NameOfClassThatContainsMap.MapName.put()

Like this

```
Class A{
public static HashMap BasicDetails;
}
```

(in the other place):

```
 A.BasicDetails.put("stuff);
```

Comment: That seemed to solve part of the problem, yet I am receiving errors how the A.BasicDetails.get("currentPersonName") is not compatible in the setText method

Comment: then you have to look at your code and think the way it works, best way to learn is by solving problems by yourself